# flutter:How to download .ics file in inappwebview?

Tags: flutter, dart, webview, flutter-inappwebview

I am using flutter_inappwebview in my Flutter app. In Safari the file is downloaded but in the in-app browser, the file just opens in the browser. I want to download the file.

How can I do this so that I can download from an in-app browser to my device?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.